# How to reopen a closed "arc diff"?

Tags: git, phabricator

Our team uses Git for code management & Phabricator's Differential tool, and the command-line tool Arcanist on each developer's machine, to generate nice-looking code-review dashboards.
I created a diff `D1` and it got successfully closed after being reviewed by my fellow developer. I created another branch from a separate git branch `B2`. Merged the code from the closed revision `D1`. When I tried to create a new diff `D2` using `arc diff`, I get the error

> Exception
>   ERR_CLOSED: This revision has already been closed.

Is there a way to create a new diff `D2`.

Answer (score 4):

If somehow you cannot create a new diff, even using `arc diff --create`, Perhaps you have a saved revision message fom earlier `arc diff` executions in *.git/arc/create-message*, with a line that say

```
Differential Revision: ... (some url)
```

Try to delete that line, or just an url after the colon. According to [this comment](https://secure.phabricator.com/T4210#180420) and my experience, this can help.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me some frustration when the above didn't work, because I was reusing the message generated from the cmd without "--create".

Answer (score 2):

If ignoring the current revision and just creating a new one (D35) fits your workflow, as it does ours, you have to specify that you want to create a new revision:

> arc diff --create master

Credit:

> http://dcycleproject.org/blog/93/arc-diff-and-errclosed-revision-has-already-been-closed.

Hope this helps mates who are struggling with the same issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @Bond for reminding. I just added some content to the answer.